# Management of not reliable commands to AWS IoT device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I'm working on IoT devices on AWS serverless infrastructure and nodeJS SDK on the device.

My devices are connected over a non-reliable connection. So I expect that some commands I send to them will never arrive at the target.

My project will provide some API REST on API Gateway that ask the one device to perform asynchronously some complex operations. After the command is sent over MQTT the HTTP connection will be closed (200).

The operation result at the end of the required operation on the device will be sent asynchronously from the device over MQTT to a AWS Lambda and then with REST call to a specific route on a server.

My problem is that when I do the request to API Gateway (and get 200) the message can't reach the device via MQTT and gets lost.

In this scenario I'll never receive an error message or timeout on my designated listening route to inform that the requested operation called previously on the REST API was never performed.

Any advice on how solve the problem in an AWS serverless IoT scenario?

I see that thing shadow can be used to change status of the device. Can I use it to send command to the device and create a timeout event in case that the device doesn't receive the data after some seconds?

My command must have a timeout because if not performed in the correct moment then it's not needed anymore.